# How to represent date and time in one excel cell?

Tags: excel, vsto

How to represent date and time in one excel cell?

There are cell formats such as date and time. But there
is no one format that includes both date and time.
How should I write both date and time in one cell then?

What I had to do is to split the date and time in two
separate cells like this:

[image]

Edit: This picture shows how I get a date and the incorrect result I get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you enter:

```
=NOW()
```

in a cell and format the cell as Custom

**dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss**

You should get what you want.

Comment: But how do I get a DateTime then in vsto c#?

Comment: **Post some of your code that either reads or sets an Excel cell.**